# when does import module at bottom of file

Tags: python

when I read a file `riak-python-client/riak/riak_object.py`. At the bottom of the file, I saw this

```
from mapreduce import *
```

what's it use for? Why just import at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is designed to put all of the module `mapreduce` in the `riak_object` namespace. If you put this import at the top of `riak_object.py`, then there would be an error because `mapreduce` imports `RiakObject` from `riak_object`, which is not defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `import` at any point in a file; you just have to make sure you don't try to use stuff from the module until after you have imported it.

If this is actually the last line *run* in the file, than it wouldn't serve any purpose. If it at the bottom of the file but inside some function or method, it might mean that that function/method is not run frequently and the author didn't want the overhead of importing `mapreduce` every time the program is run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific reasoning for that project, but just put the imports at the top of your file. This makes the dependencies far easier to track, and it is recommended by [Python's style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Technically, the code that is imported by an `import` statement is only available after the `import` statement has been executed. This means that when you put it at the bottom of your file, you can't use anything imported there in that file (on module level). Functions in that file *can* use the imports... but it's just bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason would be that `riak_object` (which doesn't seem to require anything from `mapreduce`?) is bringing into its namespace all the values (or those specified by `__all__`) from `mapreduce` as some kind of convenience.